# Can I use Github as hosting for dynamic websites? If so, how?

Tags: github

Static webs can be uploaded and (probably) work. But what about the dynamic ones?
I use these languages and frameworks: PHP, MySQL, Laravel, Node.js, MongoDB.
What about Bootstrap? Javascript should work...

Comment: No you can't. Github Pages does not support dynamic sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub Pages is for static websites only.  That is, websites that consist entirely of (X)HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and other static assets.

GitHub Pages doesn't support dynamic websites or anything requiring a backend or secret data.  There are other sites that provide this kind of hosting, such as Netlify and Heroku, along with many others.  You can also host those yourself on a VPS for relatively cheap.